# Trouble loading a font using SFML's Font function loadFromFile

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to use the SFML library to create a sort of text interface in c++, but i ran into an error trying to load a font.

My code looks like this

```
sf::Font font;
    if (!font.loadFromFile("courbd.ttf"))
    {
        std::cout << "Can't load the font file" << std::endl;
    }
```

and both the code I'm trying to load the font from and the font are in this path:

```
C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\PruebaSFML\PruebaSFML
```

I tried using the whole path to load the font but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, loadFromFile is going to take a path starting from the file the code is in. Here is an example from when I worked with SFML:

```
if (!font.loadFromFile("Ressources\\Fonts\\CrimsonText.ttf"))
        return false;
```

The cpp file is at the same level of the Ressources folder. Also, dont forget to use 2x \ to escape the character, because it's used to make instruction in the string like \n for a new line. So make sure of the location of the font file from the cpp file and if you need to use a path, use \ to separate folders.